# Save created div to database

Tags: javascript, php, sql

User creates new element/node (div) via javascript on click of a button. The new element is saved as "part" of the page through sql.

I dont need a solution, I just need a starting-point. If known, then best practices.

Need better search terms. Thats all.

NB. What I'm finding is how to save the content of the div to sql. That I know. As well as how to create new elements. I suspect its done through fx ID and looping. But I'm not being precise enough when searching.

Comment: So what is it that you _don't_ know?  What is your exact question here?  Are you looking for a WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: You can save the string representation of the div element, although I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want.

Comment: @PatrickQ Hey Patrick. Well not exactly. What I do know is how to use AJAX > PHP > SQL to save forms and contenteditable divs. What I don't know is how to save an dynamically created div (trough JS) - and not just the content but the new div as part of the page, in lack of a better wording/term - which is what I'm missing and makes it hard to talk about.

Comment: @JClassic This might be it. Would that be something on the lines of saving the structure in json?

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) will help you. Keep in mind, that this is going to render correctly without all the original styling.

Comment: @JClassic Yeah it's a good starting point. Thanks again, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starting point, you're going to need to learn AJAX.

Then, you'll need to extract the contents of a div and send it back to the PHP which will put in your database. Given that it seems you're a novice, I recommend using jQuery to do this.

So, as a starting point, to extract the contents of a div using jQuery do the following:

```
//Let's say your div is as follows:
<div id="some_div">Here you have some content</div>
//Here's the jQuery to extract the contents:
var divText = $("#some_div").html();
```

From there, you'll need to use AJAX to send it to PHP to write it to your database. It should be noted that if they're creating a NEW div, you'll need to reference an existing div on the page first and then the created div as a child of that because you're inserting something in to the DOM that wasn't already there and your Javascript won't be aware of it. So you'll have to learn about "delegation" also.

It sounds like a lot to learn but we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: Hey @Difster, thank you. I'm using AJAX > PHP > SQL to save forms and contenteditable divs. This part "It should be noted that if they're creating a NEW div, you'll need to reference an existing div on the page first and then the created div as a child of that because you're inserting something in to the DOM that wasn't already there and your Javascript won't be aware of it. So you'll have to learn about "delegation" also." Was what I was looking for. If you have anything else in that direction its appreciated. Otherwise this was a starting point.

Comment: I created this script on JS fiddle to demonstrate delegation. If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as solved. Thanks.
https://jsfiddle.net/cbtrzozt/

Comment: Thank you, it's appreciated. This got shot down quickly as expected - I've marked you as the answer.